# How can I fix this error I get when I try to build the GameLift Server SDK with msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, msbuild, unreal-engine4, amazon-gamelift

how can I fix this error I get when I try to build the GameLift Server SDK with msbuild? I followed the documentation exactly except for the difference that I use VS 2019, so instead of `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DBUILD_FOR_UNREAL=1 ..` `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -DBUILD_FOR_UNREAL=1 ..` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gamelift/latest/developerguide/integration-engines-setup-unreal.html#integration-engines-setup-unreal-setup.

```
"C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (3) ->
"C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\thirdparty\sioclient.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (6) ->
"C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\thirdparty\boost.vcxproj" (Standardziel) (7) ->
(CustomBuild Ziel) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(241,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.
2\out\CMakeFiles\2ec3c1b17283774f59239a3fa4dba32a\boost-configure.rule;C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\CMakeFiles\2ec3c1b17283774f59239a3fa4dba32a\boost-build.rule;C:\GameLift_06_03_202
1\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\CMakeFiles\2ec3c1b17283774f59239a3fa4dba32a\boost-install.rule;C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\CMakeFiles\32773715a79811cf3
ae535cbbe439159\boost-complete.rule;C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Release-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\CMakeFiles\88be81ce59bf5314cd0e54aba58b5cc1\boost.rule' exited with code 1. [C:\GameLift_06_03_2021\GameLift-SDK-Rele
ase-4.0.2\GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-3.4.2\out\thirdparty\boost.vcxproj]
```